# Cannot edit my Stack Overflow profile

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, profile-page

I am getting an error when I try to edit my profile and settings. I searched on meta but couldn't find an up-to-date topic on that issue.

Clicking the link directs me to this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/edit/1554691

And I get the following error message:

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred
>   while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded
>   and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional
>   information about this error, do so at our feedback site,
>   http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I just edited something on my profile and it worked fine. Can you add details saying what you did, the browser/OS you are using, any errors that are shown on screen or in the console.

Comment: I edit the error details.

Comment: You left out 70% of what was requested by @tanner's comment. What browser/OS are you using? Are there any errors shown in your browser's console?

Comment: I was just about to open a question for the same issue. I could not get to the jobs section with the same error. It seems there was a high peak in load or sth. like this on SO. After waiting 2 minutes and reloading the page everything worked fine. So just try to relax and reload the page :)

Comment: We had a misbehaving web server which may have caused this - I took it out of rotation. Can you confirm if this is still happening?

Comment: @Oded now it works. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a misbehaving web server out of rotation.

This seems to have helped the problem the OP was having.